# Redirecting 301 Page to url and Subpage to a different url

Tags: wordpress, .htaccess, redirect

I try to redirect a page to an url and subpages to a different url. But subpages are now redirected to the frontpage. I guess because the first redirect interferes the 2nd one. Can you please help?

The current setup:

```
# BEGIN 301 Redirects
Redirect 301 /page/ /new-page/
Redirect 301 /page/a/ /kb/different-page/
```

page is redirecting properly to the new-page but subpage /a/ is leading to an 404 and therefore to frontpage.

Thanks for your help guys.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try reordering your `Redirects` .

```
 Redirect 301 /page/a/ /kb/different-page/
 Redirect 301 /page/ /newpage
```